# Omitting getters & setters from wsdl2java-generated code

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, wsdl2java

How can wsdl2java omit getters & setters from generated code?

Comment: Are you wanting to have the getters and setters omited ? Or is this the problem you are experiencing ?

Answer (score 1):

Built-in - it can't.

But you can develop and configure an XJC plugin which would replace the code generation strategy used by XJC.

You'll need to implement a [FieldRendererFactory](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/master/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/xjc/generator/bean/field/FieldRendererFactory.java) and set it via [Options](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/master/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/xjc/Options.java).

But it's rather hard to do.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait a bit to accept your answer, in case someone else has written an XJC plugin to do this, so they can still see it as unanswered and mention their plugin.